# Odd Schedule Group C at the FIFA World Cup 2014

Tags: football, trivia, world-cup

Having seen the schedules for the different groups in the **[group stage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup#Group_stage)**, at the FIFA World Cup 2014, I noticed in **[Group C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_C)** an odd starting time.

It is match number 6 on the 14<sup>th</sup> of June 2014, between Ivory Coast and Japan, that starts at 22.00 (**[UTC-03](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Brazil#Bras.C3.ADlia_official_time_-_BRT_.28UTC-03.29)**).

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [fifa website](http://www.fifa.com/WORLDCUP/MATCHES/index.html), four matches are scheduled on Saturday 14 June:

- Colombia vs Greece at 13:00 (local time),
- Uruguay vs Costa Rica at 16:00 (local time),
- England vs Italy at 18:00 (local time),
- Côte d'Ivoire vs Japan at 22:00 (local time)

Four matches are needed on Saturday 14 June because only one match will be played on Thursday 12 June after the opening ceremony.
The late starting time is needed in order to observe 3 hours between every starting time